# What depends on HOME variable in EGit?

Tags: eclipse, git, configuration, repository, egit

If home environment variable is not set, EGit displays a message like this

[image]

I don't want to set my HOME variable but want Git store it's data in special directory.

I set `Default repository folder` in Git config tabs in Eclipse.

What other things will go into default HOME in such a situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't think there is anything else. (I also only set the 'Default repository folder' in EGit preferences)